# How to integrate openssl to Android?

Tags: android, c, linux, openssl

I want to use the RSA of openssl, so I need integrate openssl to Android with ndk.I download the source of openssl for Android at https://github.com/aluvalasuman/OpenSSL1.0.1cForAndroid.
`ndk-build` in the source folder generated `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`, I copied them to $(MY_PROJECT)/jni/lib/, then linked them in `Android.mk` like that:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LIBS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcrypto libssl
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := jni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And tested the openssl like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>

#define nr_bits 2048

int test_openssl()
{
  RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(nr_bits, 65537, NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it , it threw the error:

```
....jni/license/license.c:10: error: undefined reference to 'RSA_generate_key'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what's the problem? I will be very grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Such `undefined reference` errors typically indicate that the compiler/linker did not find libcrypto.so in it's path. You could try a couple of things:

1. Add -lcrypto to LOCAL_LDLIBS. This tells the compiler to use libcrypto.so, if possible, to resolve undefined symbols
2. Add $(MY_PROJECT)/jni/lib/ to LOCAL_LIBS so the compiler knows where to pick -lcrypto from. This assumes that $(MY_PROJECT) is defined in the make file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if someone is experiencing this problem, she or he could solve the problem by using:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := crypto
```

instead of

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcrypto libssl
```